# How do I edit the footer in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: layout, footer, magento2, edit

My footer consists of

`"Name | Address | Phone | Twitterlink | Facebooklink"`

I cannot find where to edit this info.

I looked under static blocks under "Footer Links", but that has nothing to do with it. I have looked at:

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml`

but there is nothing there.

Comment: Check-in backend blocks

Answer (score 0):

The location of your footer template depends on the theme you are using.

If  it is not defined in backend static blocks, you can check somewhere under:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<vendor_theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

As a last chance, make a search for the string '

```
grep -RlFin "string_to_search" app
```